# How to unpack rar/zip archive after it was uploaded via FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django, zip, archive, rar

My model

```
class Banner(models.Model):
    ...
    html5_banner = models.FileField(upload_to='banners/html5/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
```

How to replace /media/banners/html5/*date*/archive.zip with /medid/banners/html5/*date*/archive/*archive_content* on model saving stage?

Comment: Why do you need archive unpacked and how are you planning to work with archive_content after unpacking?

Comment: I want to extract html file from it and paste into iframe in my template with corresponding js and css also included into archive

Comment: So there always will be only one file in archive?

Comment: each archive contains one .html file, one .js file and two folders with images and js correspondingly